# How can I quickly reinitialize Dragon NaturallySpeaking after the microphone got saturated?

Tags: microphone, dragon-naturally-speaking

From time to time the microphone in Dragon NaturallySpeaking gets saturated:

[image]

How can I quickly reinitialize Dragon NaturallySpeaking such a situation?

Clicking on the microphone button works but I have to wait for typically around 20 seconds. Is there any faster way to  reinitialize Dragon NaturallySpeaking so that I can continue dictating?

I use Dragon NaturallySpeaking 12.5 professional on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

I know that I can reduce the occurrence of such events by changing the microphone volume.

Comment: I haven't found any answer so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.